# Running Linux Mint 20.1: HDMI max is 1920X1080 I want 2560X1440

Tags: linux-mint, display, hdmi

I was using a DP output from a HP Elite Desk 800 G2:Linux Mint 20.1. My monitor (AOC) was on 2560X1440. It has 2 ports an HDMI and the DP. The DP has failed, the HDMI is good. I confirmed this by putting a DP input from my windows pc and "nothing". I tested the DP cable on another monitor and its good. So I am now using the hdmi output from the Elite Desk but linux mint shows a maximum display setting of 1920X1080. I know it can output high resolutions from the HDMI (according to specs) so I assume it is a Linux problem. (I also checked the hdmi cable(s) I am using and they v1.4 and carry 4K+ on the other PCs.)

Can I increase the output of the hdmi port to be higher than what it displays. Here is the output of xrandr:

$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 699mm x 393mm
1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94
1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
1280x1440     59.91
1680x1050     59.88
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1440x900      59.90
1280x960      60.00
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
832x624       74.55
800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25
720x576       50.00
720x480       60.00    59.94
640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
720x400       70.08
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
2560x1440 (0x7b3) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz

Thank You.